# How to encrypt data in transit for AWS Amplify GraphQL DataStore?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify, flutter-aws-amplify

I have a Flutter application that uses AWS Amplify DataStore (API GraphQL). I need to encrypt data in transit when I create/update a model/new entry in the DataStore. How can I enable this?

Comment: Isn't it all HTTPS by default?

Comment: @jarmod I know that AWS Storage (using S3) is, for sure. AWS Amplify Cognito seems to be, too, according to their official documentation. Didn't find anything for AWS DataStore. They say DynamoDB is encrypted at rest, which DataStore uses. Nothing is clear for transit, though.